# apue.h on macOS

Tags: c, libraries

I follow these steps in order to install apue.h on macOS:

1. `make` in the `apue.3e` folder. No errors here. I also tried `make CC=/usr/bin/clang` as another user suggested in another topic.
2. Copied the libraries:

```
sudo cp ./lib/libapue.a /usr/local/lib
sudo chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libapue.a
sudo cp ./include/apue.h /usr/local/include
sudo chmod 644 /usr/local/include/apue.h
```

3. Run a test file: `gcc test.c -o test -lapue`
   But I get the following error: `error: implicit declaration of function 'open' is invalid in C99`

I have no idea of how to install correctly the library in macOS. What I have to do now?

Test.c:

```
#include <apue.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int fd = open("test.txt", O_CREAT);
        printf("Hello, world!\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Uhm, so embarassing. The library was correctly installed, I tried with the `open` function because I asked a test code to chatGPT and it wrote me this code. I'm sorry and thanks for your replies.

Comment: can we see your code please

Comment: `#include <fcntl.h>`

Comment: `man open`.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open` is a standard UNIX call, not part of apue

```
int fd = open("test.txt", O_CREAT);
```

you need to include its header

```
#include <fcntl.h>
```

see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my inattention.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea of how to install correctly the library in macOS

To show the default library directories, run this:

```
clang -Xlinker -v
```

To see the include path, run this:

```
clang -x c -v -E /dev/null | & grep '/include'
```

On Intel, the `/usr/local` path is probably good. However, on Arm, you likely need to use `/opt`.

Also, if you need to add a new INCLUDE directory, set an environment variable:

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/homebrew/include
```

Comment: this is not an include nor a lib issue, the compiler is complaining that it has not seen a declaration for the function open

Comment: Fair, I answered the quoted question "I have no idea of how to install correctly the library in macOS"